# MIPS - and instruction of zero - Register

Tags: mips, code-analysis

I've got the instruction to understand a MIPS - code. One line of it is the following one:

and $t6, $zero, $zero

Which purpose does it have ? There is the and - instruction of two zero - constants. So the result should also be zero ? But why is the and - command in usuage here ?

Thanks a lot !

---

I've tried the MARS - Simulator for MIPS - Processors and watched the registers. But the register never reaches a different value than zero after the and - command.

Comment: It's just one of the many ways to clear a register. (Ie set `$t6` to zero)

Answer (score 0):

The and instruction (`and rd, rs, rt`) performs a bitwise logical AND between `rs` and `rt` and stores the result in `rd`.

So in your example, `and $t6, $zero, $zero` would perform a logical and between 0 and 0 yielding also 0 and that value is stored in $t6 (overwriting its previous value).

Example:

```
 li $t6, 0x1234 # store 0x1234 in $t6
 # ... maybe some other unrelated code
 and $t6, $zero, $zero  # stores 0 in $t6
```

Comment: OP seems to know what `and` does. The question is, why someone would do `and $t6 $zero $zero` instead of for instance `move $0 $zero`.

Comment: @derpirscher OP has stated he tried with MARS apparently many times watching the registers after executing that instruction and never reaching a different value than zero, so I believe he is not 100% certain how that instruction works, hence my example.

Comment: Citing OP *"There is the and - instruction of two zero - constants. So the result should also be zero"* ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I've tried gusbro's code in MARS. But I can not get any different value than 0. Is it even possible with that AND - instruction of two zero - values ? I personally don't think so, because I know, what the boolean AND does and the MIPS - AND seems to be the same for every bit of a word. So why would someone use the AND - instruction instead of "move $0 $zero" ? I think, that using the AND - instruction is just a waste of the processor - potential, when you could use the move - instruction as well.

Comment: @Coder: my example was to show why would someone use `and $t6, $zero, $zero` to put a 0 onto register $t6, assuming it had originally another value.  Every instruction in MIPS has the same size. `move $t6, $0` would have the same effect (put a `0` in $t6) but `move` is a pseudo-instruction. MIPS does not have a move instruction. It is "assembled" by the compiler to another real instruction that copies the contents of a register onto another. It is compiled by MARS onto a this instruction `addu $t6, $0, $0`.

Comment: Both instructions (`and $t6, $0, $0` and `addu $t6, $0, $0` have the same effect of leaving `$t6` with the value 0 and both consume the same resources; neither instruction wastes more processor than the other).

Answer (score 0):

The real reason is because `move` and `li` don't actually exist. These are known as *pseudo-instructions* (essentially standardized macros.)

So when you write
`move $t0, $zero`
the CPU is actually running `and $t0,$0,$0`.

Similarly, `li $t0, 0x20` is actually `ori $t0, $zero, 0x20` or sometimes `addi $t0, $zero, 0x20` depending on the implementation.

Now you may be wondering, why does MIPS work like this? MIPS is known as a Reduced Instruction Set Computer, which means it has fewer possible instructions than a computer like x86. In addition, unlike x86, every instruction takes up 4 bytes in memory, regardless of what the instruction is doing. This makes the CPU's job much easier. Unlike x86, MIPS doesn't need to calculate how far to advance `$pc` after each instruction since the answer is always 4. As a result, MIPS is more efficient at executing the small list of instructions it does have, despite sometimes needing more steps to achieve what other computers can do in one line of code.

Here's an example:

```
main:
j foo      ;0x00000000
nop        ;0x00000004
nop        ;0x00000008
nop        ;0x0000000C

foo:
nop        ;0x00000010
```

If you think about it, what is `j foo` really? Couldn't you also represent that as `addiu $pc, $pc, 0x10`? After all, that's essentially what's happening.